# How to call javascript methods that are not in scope but utilise .call(this)

Tags: javascript

I am unsure on how to call these functions such as inventoryCheck in a web browser (chrome) console when it seems not visible. Is there a way I can call this? Thanks!

Below is a snippet of a javascript file.

```
(function() {
    var CC, addToBagCheck, addToCartError, addToCartRequest, addToCartSuccess, availableSizes, displayCorrectShoe, inventoryCheck, isValidJSON, processInventory, selectSize, showBuy, showError, showSoldOut,
        slice = [].slice,
        bind = function(fn, me) {
            return function() {
                return fn.apply(me, arguments);
            };
        };

    inventoryCheck = function() {
        return availableSizes(function(product) {
            return processInventory(product);
        });
    };

    window.captchaResponse = function(response) {
        $('#captcha').addClass('checked');
        $('#flashproductform').append('<input class="captcha-duplicate" type="hidden" name="x-PrdRt" value="' + response + '">');
        return addToBagCheck();
    };

}).call(this);
```

Comment: Why are you `bind`ing manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot. `inventoryCheck` is defined inside a closure. In order to call them globally (like in the console), you must define them on the `window` object. Since your closure appears to have `window` as its context (by calling it using `this` as context), then you can define `inventoryCheck` like:

```
this.inventoryCheck = function(){...}
```

Note that defining stuff on the global object is a bad idea. Consider attaching everything to a single global object you own. This reduces your footprint on the global object to just a single object. The following pattern is better:

```
;(function(ns){

  ns.inventoryCheck = function(){...}

  // the rest of the code

})(this.myGlobal = this.myGlobal || {});

// Usage

myGlobal.inventoryCheck(...);
```

Comment: Thank you! I assume calling window.captchaResponse is also a no-go as it stands?

Comment: To add to this, captchResponse is added to the window object in the above code, so will be available via window.captchResponse().  But the above recommendation is a better way of adding things to window.

Comment: @hello Your `window.captchaResponse` is an exception. Since nothing is shadowing `window`, then `window` in that scope _is_ the global `window`. That means you're defining `captchaResponse` globally (i.e. it will be visible on the console). However, as mentioned, attaching to the global is a bad idea.

Comment: @user2263572 Thanks guys! One more thing, is it possible to call the window object instead of all the individual bindings eg: window.captchaResponse, window.captchaError etc. I didn't write this and I'm unsure to how to call all the window objects in order change the site's appearance after doing so.

Comment: This is the full script if you need to have a look. http://paste.ofcode.org/35up3zKRVRhmAWzUAUiwZ85 Thanks !